# How do I get Google Analytics to track individual images on a slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, statistics, google-analytics, slideshow

I have a jQuery slideshow, I'm using the cycle plugin. I'm decent with jQuery, but I don't know how I should tie it in with Google Analytics to show me how many times each image is requested.

I've looked around online but **I haven't been able to find any good documentation for it.**

Can someone give me a simple example and maybe a link to the documentation supporting the example?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

The key is just to use this code to send an event:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'PageLocation', location.href]);
```

But you need to have the asyncronous syntax of calling Google Analytics, which will probably look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxx-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'site.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

BTW you might need to wait for the document to be ready / loaded before executing the _gaq.push line :)

Comment: I'd love to help, but I don't know what you're looking at. Perhaps you can provide some sample code.

Comment: I tried to clarify a little. It's working for me now, the edit was help others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this. Analytics is about the page in relation to how the users interact with it.

If you had a random image being shown first on a page it could be useful to know which one is causing the biggest bouncerate, or if your images in the slideshow were hyperlinked and you wanted to know which one is gathering the most click-through to other pages, but the ammount of times an image is loaded is a pretty arbitrary statistic.

Event tracking is probably what you should be looking at, but im unsure of what you are trying to do with the tracking data... if you give a better explanation id be more then happy to help.

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html

......

Comment: Well, a client has analytics installed and they want to use it with their slideshow / gallery to get data for which images people are looking at the most. I hadn't heard of using analytics in this way before either. Maye that's why I couldn't find much information about it online. Anyhow, I'll take a look at your resources. Thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: You could also look into using _trackPageview to call a fake pageview everytime an image is loaded.

Although then you get the problem of creating "fake views" to your site, which will impact your clients reports...

http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55529

Comment: I thought about that, too, because the images could be identified by their URI. I installed _trackEvent for now, after a little time of having it record data I'm going to look at analytics and see if I can make sense of what it's recording. Hopefully that will be the way to go! Thanks again!

Comment: Any idea how long it takes for the data to register in Analytics once event tracking is installed?

Comment: The data will be recorded from the moment it is sent to analytics, but analytics takes (from my experiences) around 6 or so hours to show up statistics in your dashboard... so I'm sure by the time you read this you should be seeing the data in there :)

Comment: I'm going to edit the question and put some of the code I'm using in, because I must be doing something wrong. I can't get the events to show up in GA. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually some of that data just started showing up so maybe it's ok. Thanks!!